# How to remove contenteditable attribute only on those how is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

i think its a simple think for thoose who know it :-)

I want to remove the attribute "conteneditable" for all elements that have **not** the attribute contenteditable="false". So only remove those how has "contenteditable=true".

How i can do it?
This will remove it on all elements

```
$('body *', iframe).removeAttr('contenteditable');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute selector: `$("[contenteditable=true]").removeAttr('contenteditable')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a `getAttribute()` function that you can use.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)